# Want to deploy a storage bucket with public readable storage object permission in GCP using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

I created a terraform file to create a Google Storage bucket with public readable Storage object permission. I am able to deploy the Storage bucket but can't assign the proper ACL against my template, I found some errors for ACL part.

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project = "${var.project}"
}

 resource "google_storage_default_object_access_control" "public_rule" {
  bucket = "google_storage_bucket.test-${var.project}"
  role   = "READER"
  entity = "allUsers"
 }

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = "test-${var.project}"
  storage_class = "standard"
  location = "US"
}
```

ERROR: attached [image]

if anyone can help me to assign permission at the time of bucket creation, will be greatfull.

Comment: You are missing one " for the second resource.

Comment: Look into this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_default_object_access_control.html). how are you importing the DefaultObjectAccessControl ?

Comment: what version of terraform-google-provider you are using?

Comment: Terraform v0.12.9 + provider.google v3.7.0 + provider.google-beta v3.7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following setup resolved my issue:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project = "${var.project}"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "viewer" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    members = [
        "allUsers",
    ] 
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "editor" {
  bucket = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}"
  policy_data = "${data.google_iam_policy.viewer.policy_data}"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = "${var.project}-xxxx"
  storage_class = "xxxxx"
  location = "xxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [Terraform Official Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_default_object_access_control.html), the function `bucket.name` is used, and it reads the bucket name from the variable `name`. You have to provide your project id in the `resource_storage_bucket` as below. I tried it and it worked correctly for me:

```
provider "google-beta" {
}

resource "google_storage_default_object_access_control" "public_rule" {
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  role   = "READER"
  entity = "allUsers"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = "[THE_BUCKET_NAME]"
  project = "[PROJECT_ID]"
  storage_class = "standard"
  location = "US"
}
```

Where `PROJECT_ID` is your Project ID and `THE_BUCKET_NAME` is the bucket name you want to put.